# SQL Server - Joining two tables directly or, sometimes, through a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I don't have control over the database setup. I have these:

Things has two fields: ListID, FormID. 
Lists also has a FormID.

So Things can join directly to FormID, or join to FormID through Lists.

If Thing.ListID is null, I want that Thing.FormID.
If Thing.ListID is not null, I want Lists.FormID.

I'm guaranteed to have either Things.FormID be NULL, or Things.ListID be NULL; never both, nor neither.

Here's what I had:

```
SELECT
    t.ThingID
FROM
    Questions q JOIN
    Forms f 
        on q.FormID = f.FormID JOIN
    Lists l
        on f.FormID=l.FormID JOIN
    Things t
        on ((t.FormID = f.FormID) OR
            (t.ListID = l.ListID))
```

Obviously, I have no idea how OR inside JOINs works.

I got this working using a `UNION`, but I didn't know if there was a smarter/faster conditional-triangle-join, something along those lines.

---

Not explained here but I want to keep joining off of ThingID. Imagine I'm going to keep joining up tables based on these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with `coalesce()` and `left outer join`:

```
SELECT coalesce(tf.ThingID, tl.thingID) as ThingID
FROM Questions q JOIN
     Forms f 
     on q.FormID = f.FormID JOIN
     Lists l
     on f.FormID = l.FormID LEFT JOIN
     Things tf
     on tf.FormID = f.FormID LEFT JOIN
     Things tl
     on tl.ListID = l.ListID;
```

This produces different results if there is a match both the form and list.  However, you have said in the question that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks very much - I want to use ThingID to keep joining to other tables. Does this work if I want to use ThingID to keep joining things?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use `coalesce()` or have multiple joins.  The multiple joins can actually perform well, assuming that indexes are set up properly.